# KeyEvent generated three times for single key release

Tags: java, javafx, keyevent

I'm writing an application that should respond to zoom commands and I'd like those to be triggered by the keyboard too (e.g., CMD/CTRL and + (or =) for zoom in). I got this working fine, apart from one strange thing: the key event for the '=' key (the normal one, at the top of the keyboard, next to the number and '-' keys), is generated three times when I hold the CMD key (I'm on a Mac). Strangely enough this doesn't happen when you don't hold the CMD key…

Below program shows what I mean:

```
package test_keypress;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test_KeyPress extends Application {

    static int nr = 0;

    public void start(Stage stage) {

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Label label = new Label("Press Key");
        Label keyReleasedTxt = new Label();
        root.getChildren().addAll(label, keyReleasedTxt);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300);

        scene.setOnKeyReleased((KeyEvent e) -> {
            keyReleasedTxt.setText("Key Released: " + e.getCode() + " = " + e.getText());
            System.out.println("Key Released: " + e.getCode() + " = " + e.getText());
            e.consume();
        });

        stage.setTitle("Key Event test");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is the output it generates:

`Key Released: EQUALS = =` <= pressing just the '=' key on the keyboard

`Key Released: EQUALS = =
Key Released: EQUALS = +
Key Released: EQUALS = =
Key Released: COMMAND =` <= when '=' is pressed together with the CMD key.

Any idea what's going on here, and how I can prevent this from happening?

Note: the numeric keypad versions of the +, - and = keys behave just fine, and so do the other keys I have tried so far; it is just the “normal” '=' key that behaves this strangely.